# Change every image view resources inside listview with one click

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I have a list view of songs with play and pause button in every row..
I can't have two pause Icon(two playing song) in my list view So I need to first reset all of them to play Icon then set the selected view to pause Icon..
How can I do this ? Or can you offer a better solution for this ?

This is my code :

In model class ( Product ) :

```
public int currentPosition= -1;
```

in **Adapter**:

```
    public interface PlayPauseClick {
    void playPauseOnClick(int position);
}
private PlayPauseClick callback;
public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
    this.callback = listener;
}
.
.
.


    holder.playPauseHive.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPauseHive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
                if (position == product.currentPosition) {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    //set the image to pause icon
                }else{
                    //set the image to play icon
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

my Callback inside my **Activity**:

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = songList.get(position);
    if(product.currentPosition == position){
        product.currentPosition = -1; //pause the currently playing item
    }else{
        product.currentPosition = position; //play the item
    }
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case I use a variable to store the current playing item position. Let say

```
int x = -1; //-1 can indicate nothing was currently playing
```

So in the `playPauseOnClick()` you can do something like this

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    if(x == position){
        x = -1; //pause the currently playing item
    }else{
        x = position; //play the item
    }
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The reason i remove `product.setPlayPauseId()` is because you really don't need them. You just need to set the play or pause icon based on your `x` varible which I created earlier. Do Something like this in your `getView()`

```
Product product = songList.get(position);
if (position == x) { 

    //set the image to pause icon
}else{
    //set the image to play icon
}
```

So once you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` your adapter will do all the work for you. Whenever the `x` variable having the value -1 none of the icon will be display the pause icon, this can also make sure only one position will showing the pause icon as well.

Hope it help you.

Comment: I've edited my code and my question based on your answer but still had no chance ..